# dynamic construction of checkboxes in a asp:table problem with events

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, autopostback

I'm currently dynamically building an **asp:table** which contains **checkboxes**
these checkboxes have a **CheckChanged** event as an **auto postback**.

```
v_articleCheckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(v_articleCheckBox_CheckedChanged);
```

I am storing the checkbox states in the viewstate and I am rebuilding the table every page load so that the viewstate may then be re applied to the check boxes.

For every checkbox but the first this works perfectly.

The odd case is that the first checkbox works on the check event but simply does not call the **v_articleCheckBox_CheckedChanged** method on the **uncheck event**

Does anyone have an idea?

I was thinking of adding a dummy checkbox as a first entry in the table and then simply hide it from the client. but this seems to be a bad workaround.

Comment: Is the first checkbox checked and the others not?

Comment: I'm curious: what was the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm curious: what was the issue? –
>   splattne (Nov 27 at 11:39)
>   I am curious too – JohnIdol (Nov 27 at
>   13:48)

I resolved the issue by modifying my logic so that some events were fired on a more generic basis and I simply avoided the issue.

I have no idea about the why or how this was occurring; I simply found a work around that suited my needs.